# Solución a Map is not a Function React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

estoy intentando utilizar map sobre un JSON que obtengo de Firebase pero al momento de implementarlo me ocurre este error ("map is not a function")

Aqui es donde obtengo el JSON mando a traer HomeFragment y le paso state.dataModels

```
getData() {

  return fetch('https://karen-yael.firebaseio.com/Models.json').then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({dataModels: responseJson});

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {

    dataModels: []
  }

}

componentDidMount() {

  this.getData();
  alert(this.state.dataModels)

}

render() {

  return (<HomeFragment data={this.state.dataModels}/>); //return

} //render
```

Este es mi Home Fragment

```
let models = this.props.data.map(function(modelData, index) {

  return (<Card>
    <CardItem>
      <Body>
        <Text>{modelData}</Text>
      </Body>
    </CardItem>
  </Card>)

});

return (<Content></Content>); //return

} //render
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que la respuesta no te regresa un objeto iterable, por lo que `map` no es una función del objeto.

Una solución puede ser que regreses un arreglo con los valores del objeto, de esta forma:

```js
fetch('https://karen-yael.firebaseio.com/Models.json').then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
    let iterableResponse = Object.values(responseJson);
    iterableResponse.map(item => console.log(item));
    //this.setState({dataModels: iterableResponse});
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Excelnte! muchisimas gracias! funciono perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

en React se usan mucho los condicionales para probar si un objeto tiene o no contenido.

```
    <Text>{modelData?}</Text>
```

Probaria de esa manera.